# Rmarkdown: different bg colours for code chunk and result (plot)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using the `architect` theme from `prettydoc` package and generating HTML output. Is it possible to have different bg colours between the code chunk and the resulting plot, and importantly control these independently. For example have a blue background for code and red for plot regions?

````
---
output:
 prettydoc::html_pretty:
 theme: architect
 highlight: github
 math: katex
---

```{r noramlity, fig.align='center', fig.height=3}
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(density(ToothGrowth$len))
hist(ToothGrowth$len, breaks=15,col="lightblue1")
```
````

I can change the code background using css

````
```{css}
.plotColor{
  background-color:red;
}

```

```{rnoramlity, fig.align='center', fig.height=3, class.source="plotColor"}
    par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
    plot(density(ToothGrowth$len))
    hist(ToothGrowth$len, breaks=15,col="lightblue1")
    ```
````

I have tried `class.output` but that didn't work